# Blackberry Plugin in Eclipse - blackberry menu item not showing up

Tags: blackberry

I followed [Installation video tutorial](http://www.blackberry.com/DevMediaLibrary/view.do?name=eclipseJDE) and installed ["BlackBerry JDE Plug-in for Eclipse 1.1](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp) " However, due to some reason, Blackberry menu is not showing up in the Eclipse.

OS is Windows 7 and [Eclipse 3.5](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/index.php).

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Blackberry menu does not show up in 3.5. You don't need the Blackberry menu for creating a Blackberry project in Eclipse.